# High CPU usage with MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

I'm running t3.large MySQL instance and having high CPU usage issue. There are tons of data stored and tables in one database. After rebooting the instance everything is pretty good and all of queries are running really well. However, CPU usage is getting higher for same queries after one day, two days etc. I guess I'm missing some configuration. Please teach me if you know about this issue.

Please let me know what information you need.
Thank you

> **UPDATE**

```
8G RAM
2 vCPU
```

Here is the result for `SHOW VARIABLES;`

```
 Variable_name  Value
auto_generate_certs ON
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF
back_log    311
basedir /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.26.R1/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format   MIXED
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size  25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.26.R1/share/charsets/
check_proxy_users   OFF
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /rdsdbdata/db/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin   mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime   0
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disabled_storage_engines    
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   200
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed_compression_period    1000
gtid_mode   OFF_PERMISSIVE
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    YES
have_statement_timeout  YES
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 668
hostname    ip-10-20-1-119
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   1475346432
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 11802771456
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_deadlock_detect  ON
innodb_default_row_format   dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_fill_factor  100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  2
innodb_flush_sync   ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_checksums    ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   /rdsdbdata/log/innodb
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth   100
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_numa_interleave  OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   30000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_cleaners    4
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_tmpdir   
innodb_undo_directory   ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_version  5.7.26
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 300
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine    InnoDB
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
keyring_operations  ON
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.26.R1/share/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin ON
log_bin_basename    /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
log_bin_index   /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password   OFF
log_error   /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
log_error_verbosity 3
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   ON
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog    OFF
log_syslog  OFF
log_syslog_facility daemon
log_syslog_include_pid  ON
log_syslog_tag  
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_timestamps  UTC
log_warnings    2
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  TABLE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 134217728
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 1305
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_execution_time  0
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_points_in_geometry  65536
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users   OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
ngram_token_size    2
offline_mode    OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    65535
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
parser_max_mem_size 18446744073709551615
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    -1
performance_schema_digests_size 10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size    10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size 10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes 80
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_index_stat   -1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_program_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   50
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  10
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    -1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   -1
performance_schema_users_size   -1
pid_file    /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
plugin_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.26.R1/lib/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    24421
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    1048576
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size    8388608
rbr_exec_mode   STRICT
read_buffer_size    561152
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    74288
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   TABLE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  ON
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
require_secure_transport    OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    /tmp/
server_id   1356210819
server_id_bits  32
session_track_gtids OFF
session_track_schema    ON
session_track_state_change  OFF
session_track_system_variables  time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info  OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys  ON
sha256_password_private_key_path    private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56   OFF
show_create_table_verbosity OFF
show_old_temporals  OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /rdsdbdata/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   60
slave_parallel_type DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
socket  /tmp/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
stored_program_cache    256
super_read_only OFF
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    UTC
table_definition_cache  15000
table_open_cache    30000
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   21
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   UTC
timestamp   1594803997.106910
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /rdsdbdata/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
transaction_read_only   OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction    OFF
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.7.26-log
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    300
warning_count   0
```

> **UPDATED**
> Here is the information for `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

```
   Variable_name    Value
Aborted_clients 349
Aborted_connects    4
Binlog_cache_disk_use   32780
Binlog_cache_use    926627
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  40
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   523370
Bytes_received  11306677183
Bytes_sent  42108060282
Com_admin_commands  1821533
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_instance  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 153612
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   675778
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   19537
Com_change_master   0
Com_change_repl_filter  0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  678106
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    123499
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 358
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  4705
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  237658
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   358
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_explain_other   0
Com_flush   2375
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  387619
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    1
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   2359
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    7884
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    48
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  22969435
Com_set_option  57156
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_create_db  1
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    30
Com_show_create_table   4
Com_show_create_trigger 5
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 89
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    196
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   83
Com_show_master_status  8
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   196
Com_show_processlist    64
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   22
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 14096
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   2
Com_show_tables 4
Com_show_triggers   2
Com_show_variables  14188
Com_show_warnings   1771
Com_show_create_user    0
Com_shutdown    0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_group_replication_start 0
Com_group_replication_stop  0
Com_stmt_execute    23713996
Com_stmt_close  22983573
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    22983590
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    1
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   8
Com_update  499949
Com_update_multi    79009
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 24426
Created_tmp_disk_tables 747848
Created_tmp_files   10144
Created_tmp_tables  1919017
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  24036025
Handler_delete  139300
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   48089725
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 1846726
Handler_read_first  19273214
Handler_read_key    3382533715
Handler_read_last   20
Handler_read_next   3745214867
Handler_read_prev   217687
Handler_read_rnd    138603436
Handler_read_rnd_next   9609179175
Handler_rollback    47
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  1469992994
Handler_write   228673280
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  Dumping of buffer pool not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200707  4:40:22
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status    Completed resizing buffer pool at 200707  5:00:01.
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   671283
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   10998300672
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  85864
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  1406795776
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    15229089
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   802
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   48299
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  720384
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   2500274
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   13043
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    16982406323
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    6841287
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    212429
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   1064918378
Innodb_data_fsyncs  7787306
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    194762347008
Innodb_data_reads   11900735
Innodb_data_writes  20757021
Innodb_data_written 503665992192
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  13963694
Innodb_dblwr_writes 1279767
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   46975162
Innodb_log_writes   3405477
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    3437770
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   25361164800
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    1561262
Innodb_pages_read   11887242
Innodb_pages_written    15229155
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    413
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    3
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    25
Innodb_row_lock_waits   104
Innodb_rows_deleted 139303
Innodb_rows_inserted    334859458
Innodb_rows_read    14455969709
Innodb_rows_updated 4371965
Innodb_num_open_files   5962
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   13390
Key_blocks_used 9
Key_read_requests   7560
Key_reads   57
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Locked_connects 0
Max_execution_time_exceeded 0
Max_execution_time_set  2834
Max_execution_time_set_failed   0
Max_used_connections    19
Max_used_connections_time   2020-07-09 03:17:35
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count 0
Open_files  50
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  7459
Open_tables 26956
Opened_files    1605746
Opened_table_definitions    569809
Opened_tables   682726
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  153610
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_index_stat_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost    0
Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost 0
Performance_schema_program_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 4
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  1031832
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   22950557
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 73743812
Questions   25952859
Select_full_join    15497
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    98104
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 19819966
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   19812
Sort_range  12
Sort_rows   91548778
Sort_scan   181778
Table_locks_immediate   73808
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   46852424
Table_open_cache_misses 682724
Table_open_cache_overflows  346069
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  13
Threads_connected   6
Threads_created 19
Threads_running 1
Uptime  707539
Uptime_since_flush_status   707539
```

> **UPDATE**
> [image]

Comment: [This is the general information required](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning). Take especial note of the slow query log.

Comment: Thanks @danblack, could you please check again? I'm not sure it's all you need.

Comment: one thing I wanna say is everything works well first 2~3 days for same queries and data load.

Comment: server settings, any my.cnf contents that is relevant to tuning.

Comment: check again? @danblack

Comment: first look trough: query_cache_size set this 0, needs to be set as well as the mode. Set your `long_query_time` down. 1 slow query seem implausible. Table_defination_cache as you'll note is at its limit - raise this. Select_scan is high as are number of rows examined wrt uptime/queries. You have slow queries that need better indexes. With long_query_time=0.1 or so you'll start to see some. Follow first link here, show some details.

Comment: Sorry, need all of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames, Added the result for `show global status;` Please post an answer!

Comment: I think this is not SQL issue because it works well for first 2 ~ 3 days under same queries(cron jobs) so I guess it's cache issue but not sure. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship - Sorry to bug you again, but my automated script croaked because `version` was missing from VARIABLES.

Comment: Added 3 lines at the bottom of SHOW VARIABLES section for mysql version. Thanks

Comment: You probably want to collect status variables while the system is misbehaving. Flush status, wait a couple of hours, then run show status again.

Comment: @danblack, Rick James, updated table_definition_cache and table_open_cache but no any improvements. please help me.

Comment: fix... your ... slow ... and ... poorly .... indexed .... queries.
Show details to get help. Read all the info, not just the parts that you want.
You cannot tune your way out of this performance problem.

Comment: Again, this is not a query issue, need to tweak some configuration, let me do  it myself.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship Is your t3.large on Dedicated or Shared server?  Do you know why com_flush is running every 5 minutes?  This causes table open thrashing. Select_scan indicates table scans are running 31 times per second average.  Indexes are needed to avoid scans. JetProfiler.com could help identify with their free trial that has no expiration date.

Comment: I'm sure it's a dedicated server.

Comment: Use of myip.ms utility software may reveal confirmation of Dedicated or Shared hosting. Scroll through output until you see nnnnn are live websites.......

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your RDS t3.large Parameter Group

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 1 to clear innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 59,407 faster
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 12,411
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 5,359
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

Please leave a comment after 7 days running with suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Wilson Hauck, I will definitely try this and let you know.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship How did it work out?

Comment: Yeah. it works great. CPU usage is around 30 ~ 40% stable now. I really appreciate. one more question. Currently CPU usage is 15% even if no running queries(idle). Added a screenshot that shows graph when instance is completely idle(checked via `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`) I have about 7000 tables and VIEWS that contains these tables. so does this cause that issue? Thank you again.

Comment: This is my question on AWS forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=323360&tstart=0

Comment: Updated question along with the latest `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`

Comment: You may use from your browser, www.myip.ms to determine if your host has you on Shared or Dedicated hosting plan.  About 50 lines into the report there is a line with nnnn live websites.   View my profile, Network profile for contact info.